# VPN Server Connectivity Issue In A System Not Directly Connected To The Router

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I have installed openvpn in one of my machine which is not directly connected to the router. But when trying to access, it says server unreachable.

Comment: A lot more details are needed.

Comment: "*Server unreachable*" suggests a problem with your network configuration, not a problem with the server. It's unclear how you intend to pass inbound VPN connections get through the router to reach the not-directly-connected (what does that mean?) VPN server.

Comment: My VPN server is one of the machines in the office that is connected through LAN Network.